# Woocommerce add to cart a specific product if a specific product is in the cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking for a plugin or snippet code (JS or PHP) to get this function.

I have 2 products on my shop, Oil for women and oil for men (100ml)

I would like to have a function on checkout page (NOT to cart page) if i buy or add to cart the women oil, i want to see a button where you can add to cart for only 3€ the men oil (30ml)

AND reverse, if i buy or add to cart the men oil, i want to see a button where you can add to cart for only 3€ the women oil (30ml)

How can i solve it?

Exist a plugin or a snippet code that i can add on checkout page? (JS or PHP)

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

WooCommerce Checkout Add-ons lets you do just that: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-add-ons/#

You should be able to add upsells to your checkout based on products in the cart.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this is downvoted. The mentioned plugin should do the trick.

Comment: the downvote is not mine but I believe this is because 
recommendations for plugins are not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), certainly the part - Answer well-asked questions - Not all questions can or should be answered here..

Comment: @7uc1f3r Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score -2):

Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) for WooCommerce
this is the plugin which I am using for checkout